# CSS file not updating

Tags: magento-1.9, css, cache, magento1.9.3, cloud

I have a `jay.css` file in directory `/public_html/skin/frontend/neighborhood/default/css` but Magento is not recognizing the file changes.

I have cloudflare and cleared the cache but it still doesn't load the updated jay.css

I deleted the jay.css file, went to the url and it still loaded the `jay.css` so it must be stored somewhere in cache but don't know where.

I went to `var/cache` and deleted all the folders, i've flushed Magento Cache and also flushed cached storage.

I added a jay1.css file to the same directory to see if it would load and when I type in the url it didn't load it.

I've also restarted my apache server and nothing seems to work. My `jay.css` doesn't up.

Comment: css merging enable in your site ??

Comment: Temporary disable cache and cloudflare or cdn settings and check.

Comment: Have you removed var/view_processed/

Answer (score 0):

It may be stored in your browsers Cache not Magento's.  If you're using Chrome click top right 3 bars for settings and go to history "clear cache".

Also if you only deleted the jay.css in your local files and not remote files it will still be there make sure you cleared it from both.

The most common error I see with problems like this is just a problem with the url and the programmer types in the wrong file path.

Comment: I've cleared my browsers cache and it still not loading the updated jay.css

Answer (score 0):

First check if your css is loaded, your website -> right click and select view page source or just press ctrl+u. There you'll find your jay.css file. Check if it is showing jay.css and the right url. Click on it, see if it is loading ok.

It should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.exemple.com/skin/frontend/neighborhood/default/css/jay.css" media="all" />
```

For this problem to happen, There are three reasons I know of:

1.) There might be an issue because of System Cache. Clean the cache from the backend or go to magentoroot/var/ and delete the contents of the cache and session folder.

2.) There can be issue with the file permission of your css File. In this case just type the following command in terminal, sudo chmod 777 -R /magentoroot/

3.) Lastly, there could be something wrong with the url in your core_config_data table of your database, which I think you have already checked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue This is the behavior of `cloudflare` or any cdn .

for this kind of issue `cloudflare` and other cdn providers provides you facility of `purging`

In cloudflare , login to clodflare

go to `caching` click on `purge individual files`

and then insert path to you css with in that

ex : `http://yourSite/skin/frontend/neighborhood/default/css/jay.css`

and then click on `purge individual files` and your file would be updated

Answer (score 0):

It might happens due to cache problem.

1. First clear your cache then reload.
2. If not succeed then use the shortcut to refresh `ctrl+f5`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/87377)

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I think it's an answer. We don't need to take care about the technical here.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh may be you right but he should ask to OP , that he has tried those are things and OP has already written all this steps in the question so that's why I think that this should be not an answer

Comment: i just wanna help. I use this way for that problem. if my answer really distrubing you, im sorry. @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: @syahidahhumairoh no buddy , here we are to improve every one knowledge and if anyone is wrong then we just tell him/her you wrong with this point and we also take care not to avoid spam answer and low quality answers.

Comment: @syahidahhumairoh you are always welcome